# Subdivide integration domain in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a function `func` defined in the domain `[-5, 5] x [-5, 5]`. I'm using [`scipy.integrate.dblquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) to perform the integration of this function on this domain.

Due to the function definition, it has a part where it is very flat and "uninteresting" and a central part (more or less the unit circle in the center of the domain), where it is "interesting". High-quality resolution in this "interesting" part is crucial for the quality of the integral.

I did a quick test to understand where the function is evaluated and produced a plot where the marked points are the evaluation points of the function. I compare this with the "interesting" part of the domain. The picture should say it all: Only a handful or points lie in tehe interesting part, while the majority lie outside, which is to expect when using a Gaussian quadrature.

[image: Visualization of interesting domain]

Here is how I generate this plot:

```
xx, yy = [], []

def func(y, x):
    xx.append(x)
    yy.append(y)
    return 1

dblquad(func, -5, 5, lambda x: -5, lambda x: 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=140)
ax.plot(xx, yy, 'x')

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=1.2, facecolor='#ffcccc', edgecolor='#ff3333')
ax.add_patch(circle)
ax.annotate(xy=[-1, -1], s='Interesting part', color='r',
        xytext=[-4, -2.6], arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'->', 'color':'r'})
```

Should I subdivide my domain is smaller parts and apply `dblquad` on all of them, then add up the results? Or will `dblquad` do it automatically if it recognizes the function to need more resolution on certain regions?

**EDIT**:
After giving a complex function to `dblquad`, I got the following warning:

`/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:356: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)`

Altough I don't find a clear statement on the documentation of `dblquad`, it is pretty obvious that the function is dynamically choosing a number of subdivisions based on the integrand. In the case I shown before, the integrand was simply 1 everywhere, thus extremely simple to integrate. When the function is not that simple, scipy will subdivide the domain.

For the records, my function looks like this:
[image: Integrand]

Comment: Have you applied `dblquad` to your function of interest and failed? What is the sampling pattern of `dblquad` in that case? I don't think the test you present, based a constant function, is representative of the sampling `dblquad` will perform for a non-trivial function.